# Get list of topics associated with consumer group kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have 20 topics, among 20 topics, 5 topics consumed by consumer1 and 15 consumed by consumer2. Is there any way to get list of topics associated with each consumer. If I pass consumer Id as a parameter/request, I want display all topics associated with that consumer.

looking for a Java or restful service program.

Answer (score 0):

`kafka-consumer-groups.sh --describe <<group.id>>` will show a list of all consumers in the group with their IDs, topics part of the group, and network addresses of the consumers. You can then `grep` by the `client.id`

Out of the box, there is no way to use the `client.id`  alone to discover consumers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin client to get information about consumer groups with listConsumerGroups function(or any other information about kafka). All utility scripts use adminclient under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

From [AdminClient](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listConsumerGroupOffsets-java.lang.String-) you can use `listConsumerGroupOffsets` to list the consumer group offsets of topics

> List the consumer group offsets available in the cluster with the default options. This is a convenience method for #listConsumerGroupOffsets(String, ListConsumerGroupOffsetsOptions) with default options.

```
ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult list = client.listConsumerGroupOffsets​("group");
```

And then you can get all topic and partitions with offset

```
KafkaFuture<Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata>> topics = list.partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata​()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<String> groupTopics = 
        adminClient.describeConsumerGroups(CollectionUtil.listOf(groupId))
        .all().get().get(groupId).members() //get group members (consumers info)
        .stream().flatMap(member ->
                member.assignment() // get active assignment for the specific member
                        .topicPartitions()
                        .stream()
                        .map(TopicPartition::topic)
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet()) // get unique topics per consumer
                        .stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // get unique topics per group

log.info("Group {} has active topics: {}", groupId, groupTopics);
```